# What type should be used for cookies values str or unicode in Python/Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies

What type should be used for cookies values str or unicode in Python/Google App Engine?

This question is trivial but very important - I wan to encrypt binary information into cookies and learn limitation.

After reading some specification I found I should use http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookie.html - whatever this library allow str and unicode.

Problems start with encoding **binary cookies**:

This code will not work - str can not be unicode

```
''.join([chr(x) for x in range(256)]).decode('utf8')
```

This code will work but what encoding should choosen 'latin1' or 'base64':

```
''.join([chr(x) for x in range(256)]).decode('latin1')
''.join([chr(x) for x in range(256)]).decode('base64')
```

Should I set cookies or headers with only **str** not with **unicode** and not care about encoding?

I will use of course `Cookie().value_encode(value)` for **str** to follow rfc and browser specific behaviour?

Can you suggest some practical solution?

Answer (score 1):

Potentially unreliable links in the cookie chain are HTTP(S) proxy servers, and user agents such as browsers and client applications.  Servers send out cookies.  These remote programs created in all kinds of computer languages may handle the cookies according to their own concepts of "strings", store the cookies in various file formats, and later return the cookies to the servers.  With so many potential failure points the safest option for binary data in cookies must be base64.